# How To Catch Invalid Firebase API key (that is entered by user)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, error-handling, api-key

I have a shell script to launch my react app that prompts the users for a firebase api key. The script then writes to a file that stores the key:

```
//api.js (script written file)
export const fireApiKey = "AIz...............................";
```

Then that file is imported and used in my firebase config file:

```
import { fireApiKey } from "../api";
.
.
.
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: fireApiKey,
    authDomain: "name-3333.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "name-3333",
    storageBucket: "name-3333.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "3333333333",
    appId: "333333333",
    measurementId: "G-333333"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const db = getFirestore(app)
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

I've attempted to try catch the initializeApp function call, but it seems even if the API key is incorrect this call still succeeds so the code that was in my catch block never was executed, but it did print an error to browser console: "GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/... 400 (Bad Request)".

If the users enters an incorrect key how do I handle/catch this error? I mostly want to just notify the user of this error.

Comment: Why are your users entering an API key?  That's neither an expected nor supported use case at all.  A Firebase config is meant to be managed by an app developer, not an end user.  I would not expect that what you're trying to do is possible, since a given configuration is expected to be correct by the SDK, or generate error messages in the log, as you're experiencing.